# Can't access resource id of MobileElement found by driver.findElementsbyClass()

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm working on an Android Test project and I need to see the resource-ids of the elements of screen. I obtain the elements via `driver.findElementsByClass()` (using AndroidDriver); when I get an element id, it's a bunch of numbers and letters and not the resource-id I see in uiautomatorviewer. Is there a way to retrieve the ids of elements?

```
List<MobileElement> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText");
String id = lst.get(0).getid();
```

Now id should be "txtpassword" however the actual value is "6ef53974-c2e0-4c1c-af48-655169716864".

Answer (score 0):

You can find the id of the element using the **Appium desktop Inspector** or **uiautomatorviewer**. You can click on the element and check if **resource-id**, **id** or **cont-desc** is visible for the element. If you don't have any unique id or automation id you can ask your developer to add it in the element.

> Using **xpath**, **class** and **name** is not recommended for appium.

If you find **resource-id** or **id** in the element, you can access the element in following way

```
MobileElement element= driver.findElementById(" element's id here");
```

If you see **cont-desc** available for element you can access the elememt in following way

```
MobileElement elemnt= driver.findElementByAccessibilityId(" element's automation id here")
```